# Are there any potential issues with passing a custom react hook as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom react hook that is used by a component but rather than getting the hook from the global context I'd like to define it in the props as below.

```
const useThingFn = () => {
  const doThing = () => console.log('Did thing')
  const data = 'hello'
  return { data, doThing }
}

const Component = ({
  // Hooks
  useThing = useThingFn,
}) => {
  const { data, doThing } = useThing();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={doThing}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Are there any potential issues with this? The purpose would be to easily mock the hooks in a test.

Comment: It's not disallowed, but there are definitely potential issues with that. For example if the prop is changed in the middle of your component's lifetime, you'll have violated the rules of hooks which will cause the application to throw an error. You're better off moving the hook definition into a separate file and mocking it using a module mock.